"from freegames import square, vector" yielding missing import error
I was coding a game in Python when I tried to run the window and realized freegames wasn't working.
I tried installing freegames, uninstalling/reinstalling it, changing my Python path, restarting my IDE, and looking for answers on Stack Overflow, yet there were no answers available. When I ran it I got an error of "Import "freegames" could not be resolved - Pylance (reportMissingImports)".
In addition, I got a separate error: Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'freegames'
File "C:\Users\my_name\OneDrive\Documents\Other Code Stuff\Python\Tron.py", line 2, in 
from freegames import square, vector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'freegames'
Output for "pip show freegames":
Name: freegames
Version: 2.5.3
Summary: Free Python Games
Home-page:
Author:
Author-email: Grant Jenks <contact@grantjenks.com>
License: Apache 2.0
Location: C:\Users\skent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:

Python path:
['C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Documents\Other Code Stuff\Python', 'c:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python312.zip', 'c:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\DLLs', 'c:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib', 'c:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312', 'c:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages']
Code to reproduce this error:
from turtle import *
from freegames import square, vector

redxy = vector(-100, 0)
redaim = vector(4, 0)
redbody = set()
 
bluexy = vector(100, 0)
blueaim = vector(-4, 0)
bluebody = set()

def inside(head):
    return -200 < head.x < 200 and -200 < head.y < 200
def draw():
    redxy.move(redaim)
    redhead = redxy.copy()

    bluexy.move(blueaim)
    bluehead = bluexy.copy()


Import "freegames" could not be resolved - Pylance (reportMissingImports) -- that is not an actual error, it is just a Pylance warning.  Did the code run successfully?

No. The game refused to run.

Then you should have gotten an actual Python error message, instead of just a Pylance warning.  Did you?

Show us the exact command you used to install the freegames module.

Yes: Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'freegames'
File "C:\Users(redacted)\OneDrive\Documents\Other Code Stuff\Python\Tron.py", line 2, in 
from freegames import square, vector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'freegames'

The command was pip install freegames.

Run this command pip show freegames and include that output in the question, and run this code import sys; print(sys.path) and also include that output in the question.

In the output for sys.path, is c:\Users\name actually c:\Users\skent ?

Yes. I edited it for privacy reasons.

Well, this is odd.  The package is installed in C:\Users\skent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages, and that directory is also present in sys.path, so I can't explain how it isn't found.

Did you run the print(sys.path) code the exact same way you run the real code?
